# Can I enter a level after I beat it?

Tags: ducktales-remastered

I just found out that there is a heart container in the Amazonas level, which I've already beaten. Can I replay that level? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately once you've cleared a stage you cannot revisit it until you start a new game.